# DataTables with AJAX - How to pass in a column hyperlink an external variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatables

I'm beginner in DataTables or dev in general :)

I use Laravel 5.4 and several DataTables which get their data using ajax calls requests and everything it's working just fine :) .
One of the tables have a column with a hyperlink on it I need to send further in the hyperlink an external variable which is not returned by Ajax response but it's hidden in same form with the table.
So, I have the table definition:

```
$('#tabelClientiOferta').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [[15, 25, 100, -1], [15,25, 100, "All"]],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: 'ajaxClienti',
      columns: [
        {data:'id',name:'id' , sClass: "hidden", "bSearchable": false },
        {data: 'denumire', name: 'denumire',
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).html("<a href='selectieFurnizor?idClient=" + oData.id + "'>" + oData.denumire + "</a>")
            }
        },
        { data: 'cui', name: 'cui' },
        { data: 'telefon', name: 'telefon', "bSearchable": false},
        { data: 'email', name: 'email', "bSearchable": false },
    ]
});
```

Controller function which respond to ajax call:

```
public function clienti(Request $request)
{
  return  Datatables::of(DB::table('clienti')->get(['id','denumire','cui','telefon','email']))->make(true);
}
```

HTML template with table and hidden variable:
@extends ('master')

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="tabelOferte" style ="width: 900px">
                    <table id = "tabelClientiOferta" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead >
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold" >
                            <td>id</td>
                            <td>Denumire</td>
                            <td>CUI</td>
                            <td>Telefon</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <input id = "hiddenId" name="hiddenId" type="text" value = {{$someId}} hidden />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

So I need to pass the hidden variable as the second parameter to the "denumire" column hyperlink, something like:

```
$(nTd).html("<a href='selectieFurnizor?idClient=" + oData.id + "&hiddenId="+$('#hiddenId') "'>" + oData.denumire + "</a>")
```

.

Is that possible?
The solution which I use now is to return a view from the controller and include in it a static DataTable (with data already prepared and sent by the controller).

Thank you for your attention
:)

Comment: Maybe. At least you should use $('#hiddenId').val().   $('#hiddenId') will not do it ;-)

Comment: Yes of course, I was on the rush when I post it, but this will not resolve my problem ..... 
Thank you

Comment: Assuming the hidden variable exists before the datatable is populated, and assuming you use the correct js code to get the value of `#hiddenId`, then what you have done should work.

Comment: Dear friends thank you for your time and attention!
I don't know what I did wrong (or good) but now it's working 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side: use add coloumn from controller

```
$data = DB::table('clienti')->get(['id','denumire','cui','telefon','email']);

return Datatables::of($data)
->addColumn('clear', function ($data) {
return '<a href="#clear-' . $data->id . '"  onclick="clear(' . $data->id . ',$(this))"  class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Clear</a>';
                })
                ->escapeColumns([])
                ->make(true);
```

And add to columns with initial js of datatables

```
{data: 'clear', name: 'cleat', orderable: false, searchable: false }
```

or use js based columns render() function, official doc and examples here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render